# How to hide the image after 3 seconds in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I display the image using img tag. I want to hide the image after three seconds.Please advise.

```
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <img src="../assets/imgs/dots.gif" height="50px" width="50px" >
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*ngIf` with the `setTimeout`

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngIf="showImage">
          <img src="../assets/imgs/dots.gif" height="50px" width="50px" >
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>

this.showImage = true;

setTimeout(()=>{  
      this.showImage = false;
 },3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a timeout

```
imageShowing = true;

ngOnInit(){
let self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
     self.imageShowing = false;     
     },3000);
}
```

in your template

```
<ion-list>
     <ion-item *ngIf="imageShowing">
       <img src="../assets/imgs/dots.gif" height="50px" width="50px" >
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```